# JPA, How to add the value of entity type in Map to primary key?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have 3 entity classes like below:-

***Role Entity***

```
@Entity
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @JoinTable(name = "roles_privileges", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "privilege_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Set<Privilege> privileges;

    // getters, setters etc

}
```

***Privilege Entity***

```
@Entity
public class Privilege {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "privileges", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Role> roles;

    // getters, setters etc

}
```

***UrlsMapper Entity***

```
@Entity(name = "urls_mapper")
@Table(name = "urls_mapper")
public class UrlsMapper {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "http_method")
    private HttpMethod httpMethod;

    @Column(name = "path")
    private String path;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @JoinTable(
        name = "u_r_p",
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "privilege_id")
    )
    Map<Role, Privilege> privilegeMap;

   // getters, setters etc

}
```

The keys, primary and foreign that get created are as below

[image]

The logs while table generation is as below:-

```
Hibernate: create table u_r_p (urls_mapper_id bigint not null, privilege_id bigint not null, role_id bigint not null, primary key (urls_mapper_id, role_id)) engine=InnoDB
Hibernate: alter table u_r_p add constraint FKgd7gd9f9ded1s28swdudqs0ro foreign key (privilege_id) references Privilege (id)
Hibernate: alter table u_r_p add constraint FKrryprkx4j60lyjti16eysn5g5 foreign key (role_id) references Role (id)
Hibernate: alter table u_r_p add constraint FKfkthdnoca59a18ba96183p7ov foreign key (urls_mapper_id) references urls_mapper (id)
```

And I just want to know how can I add the privilege_id also into the JoinTable u_r_p and if there can be other best options for this. Manually doing in the database is a obvious alternate, but i wanted to know the hbm2ddl.auto based solution, so that code manages it itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you've modeled your concepts properly. You have a `ManyToMany` between `Role` and `Priviledge` but what makes `UrlMapper` an entity? You have a `Map<Role, Privilege>` field in `UrlMapper` but that is the purpose of the join table so there should be no need to duplicate that. Instead it seems to be that `HttpMethod` and `Path` are attributes of the relationship.

[image]

However, I might also note that you seem to be expecting there be a Role/Privilege join for many different HttpMethod/Path combinations. This seems incredibly fine grained and an operations nightmare, but whatever. Anyway, what you seem to be saying is you want unique combinations of Role/Privilege/HttpMethod/Path so you should just make a entity for that and the table represents your set. Make a Permission entity that holds a unique Role/Privilege/HttpMethod/Path. Role, Privilege, HttpMethod, and even Path are essentially enumerations so you should have a table for each for each of them with `ManyToOne` mappings in the Permission entity. You could add bidirectional `OneToMany` mappings in each of the lookup tables but I'm not sure I see a need for that. It's up to you.

[image]

I assume `Privilege` would be {allow, deny} but it seems like less of a tangle if you assume deny unless a Role/HttpMethod/Path permission specifically exists. If that's the case then I would leave out the `Privilege` entity. Anyway, just a thought. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks a lot for such a elaborated answer and understanding it so clearly. I changed it to one table with onetomany(ies) of all those fields

Comment: No worries. Also, you need to have `ManyToOne` mappings in the Permission entity and that's probably be all you need. See edit. There should be no need for a bidirectional relationship but that's up to you.

Comment: Yes ManyToOne, see here -> https://github.com/krnbr/boot/tree/master/src/main/java/in/n2w/boot/entities